# Accessing static resource from ZIP files in Aura component - <ltng:require

Tags: lightning-aura-components, static-resources

I uploaded my zip file which contains css and js folder here is my zip folder structure:

static resource name: **mystaticresources**

```
myuploadzip.zip 
     --js
         jquery211.js
         myjs1.js
     --css
         mycss.css
```

Aura component:

```
<ltng:require 
          styles="{!$Resource.mystaticresources + '/myuploadzip/css/mycss.css'}" 
 scripts="{!join(',', 
          $Resource.mystaticresources + '/myuploadzip/js/jquery211.js', 
          $Resource.mystaticresources + '/myuploadzip/js/myjs1.js')}"                  
 afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" />
```

Controller:

```
 doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        jQuery("document").ready(function(){
          alert('loaded');

      });
    },
```

I could not able to see what is wrong with the above code? I'm not getting alert!

I have jquery upload as a file without zip file and I have this reference in my component then it works:

```
 <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jquery211}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit1}"/>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full code so I can try to reproduce?

Comment: Do you see any errors in console for the case that's not working ? Have scripts been successfully loaded ?

Comment: I started seeing the error now `net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` and trying to fetch from `https://myawesome-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1575229828000/mystaticresources/myuploadzip/js/jquery211.js` hmmm i'm not sure why i'm getting 404

Answer (score 2):

## ZIP Inside ZIP

If you have a ZIP inside the ZIP, this will fail. You can't access the resources inside of that file, as the system won't repeatedly/recursively decompress files this way.

You can verify this by downloading the static resource itself in your browser:

```
https://myawesome-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1575229828000/mystaticresources/
```

If the first entry you see is a ZIP file, your static resource won't work the way you expect. To fix this, ZIP the files you want into a ZIP, but do not ZIP that ZIP.

## Normal ZIP Without Internal ZIP

The *name* of the ZIP isn't included in the file path; simply start from the `js` and `css` folders:

```
<ltng:require 
          styles="{!$Resource.mystaticresources + '/css/mycss.css'}" 
 scripts="{!join(',', 
          $Resource.mystaticresources + '/js/jquery211.js', 
          $Resource.mystaticresources + '/js/myjs1.js')}"                  
 afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" />
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for your reply but unfortunately it does not work with your suggestion :(

Comment: @NickKahn Did you fix your file?

Comment: I don't have zip inside zip, I have posted the structure of my zip folder in my question so I have a zip file within that zip file I have two folders.

Comment: so if I open a new browser and try to access this page `https://myawesome-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1575229828000/mystaticresources` I do get the zip file downloaded but when I try to do `https://myawesome-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1575229828000/mystaticresources/js/jquery211.js` I get 404

Comment: @NickKahn What's in your zip file?

Comment: my zip file name is  `myuploadzip.zip`

Comment: @NickKahn Once it's in salesforce... it no longer has that name. It takes on the name of the static resource. There should not be a zip inside a zip.

Comment: yes I understand that but why do i get 404 when I try to access `https://myawesome-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1575229828000/mystaticresources/js/jquery211.js`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101812/discussion-between-sfdcfox-and-nick-kahn).